# Use an existing wampserver from a windows partition on linux mint

Tags: linux-mint, apache-httpd, mysql, php, webserver

I dual boot Windows 7 and Linux Mint 14.

I have wampserver installed on Win 7 and have a couple of websites already set up there.

Is it possible to use that same installation apache/mysql/php installation on Linux Mint?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're actually asking 3 questions:

#### Can I run the entire WAMP software stack I have from Windows on Linux

The software that's on Windows 7 is not compatible with Linux so that won't work.

#### Can I run my configuration setup of WAMP on Linux

Yes and no. Yo can't just take you Apache's httpd.conf file from Windows to Linxu since it will have references to C:\WAMP.. which isn't a valid path on Linux. These paths will have to be adjusted.

Additionally you'll have to do the same for PHP and MySQL.

#### Can I take my site content from Windows to Linux

This is actually the easiest method for taking web content from one environment to the other. You'll have to pull both the files that make up the site along with the contents of your MySQL database over from the Windows side and import them into a duplicate MySQL server setup on the Linux side.

If you're looking for an easy migration you might want to check out the XAMP project. It's similar to WAMP where it's an out of the box stack of all the tooling you get with WAMP.

http://www.apachefriends.org/en/xampp.html